Как разместить 3 div равномерно? С возможностью двигать каждый block за divider и он будет изменяться в размерах
Мне нужно сделать 3 равномерных div блока. 2 рядом друг с другом и один снизу
Сейчас реализовано: между 2 блоками (которые сверху) есть линия за которую можно перетягивать, в результате чего один блок будет уменьшаться, а другой расширяться или наоборот.
Нужно: чтобы правильно отрисовывался block3 и divider2, сейчас линия находится слева, нужно чтобы была сверху. Когда оттягиваешь divider2 наверх block2 и block1 уменьшались, а block3 увеличивался или наоборот. Также важно чтобы block3 не уходил вниз(из поля зрения, за границу экрана).


window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  resizeDiv();
});

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  resizeDiv();
});

function resizeDiv() {
  const divElement = document.querySelector('.fixedSizeDiv');
  divElement.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
  divElement.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
}




const divider = document.getElementById('divider');
const block1 = document.getElementById('block1');
const block2 = document.getElementById('block2');
let isResizing = false;

divider.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  isResizing = true;
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (isResizing) {
    const containerRect = document.querySelector('.container').getBoundingClientRect();
    const xPos = e.clientX - containerRect.left;
    const percent = xPos / containerRect.width;

    block1.style.flex = percent;
    block2.style.flex = 1 - percent;
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  isResizing = false;
});
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Запрещаем прокрутку на всей странице */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.fixedSizeDiv {
  width: 100vw;
  /* Ширина блока равна ширине экрана */
  height: 100vh;
  /* Высота блока равна высоте экрана */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Запрещаем прокрутку в блоке */
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  /* Ширина контента в блоке */
  height: 1000px;
  /* Высота контента в блоке (больше высоты блока) для появления прокрутки */
}

.container-platform {
  display: flex;
}

.block-platform {
  flex: 1;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #F9F9F3;
  overflow: auto;
}

.divider {
  width: 5px;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  background-color: gray;
}
<div class="fixedSizeDiv">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container-platform">
      <div class="block-platform" id="block1">
        <p>Первый блок</p>
      </div>
      <div class="divider" id="divider"></div>
      <div class="block-platform" id="block2">
        <p>Второй блок</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-platform">
      <div class="divider" id="divider2"></div>
      <!--Сейчас линия слева, а нужно чтобы была сверху-->
      <div class="block-platform" id="block3">
        <!--К id нужно применить js чтобы можно было его двигать-->
        <p>Третий блок</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




если проблема в том, что линия на всю высоту - то добавьте .divider  align-self: flex-start

Нет, линия divider1 упирается ровно в block3, а линию divider2 не понимаю как расположить горизонтально над block3 с возможностью эту линию тянуть

значит container-platform  - position: relative, a .divider -  position:absolute или убрать у .container-platform - display:flex

Думаю, что для вашей задачи больше подойдёт grid, а не flex:


let dir_r = null;

function fResizeStart() {
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', fResizeMove);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => document.removeEventListener('mousemove', fResizeMove));
  dir_r = this;
}

function fResizeMove(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  if (dir_r == div_v) { grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = `min(${cell1.clientWidth + ev.movementX}px, calc(100% - 4px)) 4px 1fr`; }
  else { grid.style.gridTemplateRows = `min(${cell1.clientHeight + ev.movementY}px, calc(100% - 4px)) 4px 1fr`; }
}

div_v.addEventListener('mousedown', fResizeStart);
div_h.addEventListener('mousedown', fResizeStart);
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.fixedSizeDiv {
  height: 100vh; width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr 4px 1fr / 1fr 4px 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'cell1 div_v cell2' 'div_h div_h div_h' 'cell3 cell3 cell3';
  height: 100%;
}

#cell1 { grid-area: cell1; background-color: #00bcd4; }
#cell2 { grid-area: cell2; background-color: #8bc34a; }
#cell3 { grid-area: cell3; background-color: #ffd54f; }

#div_h { grid-area: div_h; background-color: #9e9e9e; cursor: ns-resize; }
#div_v { grid-area: div_v; background-color: #9e9e9e; cursor: ew-resize; }
<div class="fixedSizeDiv">
  <div id="grid">
    <div id="cell1"><p>Первый блок</p></div>
    <div id="div_v"></div>
    <div id="cell2"><p>Второй блок</p></div>
    <div id="div_h"></div>
    <div id="cell3"><p>Третий блок</p></div>
  </div>
</div>



